# ioredis (nodejs): Debugging custom command with lua script

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I wrote a custom lua script so that I could run it from `ioredis` within my node process:

```
REDIS_CLIENT.defineCommand('my_command', {
            lua: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './lua_scripts/my_command.lua'), {
                encoding: 'utf8'
            })
        });
```

I want to add prints inside my `my_commands.lua` so when I run `client.my_command(args)` it will be printed to the nodejs process `stdout` but when I added `print "hello lua"` it did not (and that makes sense).

Is there a way to print stuff out of the lua custom script into my nodejs process stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way of doing that, but there are a few indirect ways that I described [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/5-methods-for-tracing-and-debugging-redis-lua-scripts). Out of these, excluding the new v3.2 integrated [Lua debugger](http://redis.io/topics/ldb) and the [Zerobrane Studio plugin](https://redislabs.com/blog/zerobrane-studio-plugin-for-redis-lua-scripts), the most useful & easiest approaches to tracing IMO are using PubSub or `ECHO` & `MONITOR`.

Comment: Very useful. תודה.

Comment: התענוג כולו שלי and feel free to ask me anything about Redis